# Rails route not finding corresponding action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Inside app/views/participants/index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag bulk_add_participants_program_path do %>
  <%= wrap_control_group do %>
    <%= text_area_tag :bulk_add_participants, :size => "60x3" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import Participants and Users" %>
<% end %>
```

But notice that the controller and route pertain to the Program model (for good UI reasons). And I think that might be related to the problem. When I render that view I get this error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"bulk_add_participants", :controller=>"programs"}
```

Which is weird because in app/controllers/programs_controller.rb:

```
  def bulk_add_participants
    puts "yay!"  # because i am troubleshooting
  end
```

And my config/Routes.rb is:

```
RepSurv::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'programs#index'

  devise_for :users, path_prefix: 'devise'
  resources :users

  resources :programs do
    resources :participants do
      resources :rounds do
        get 'survey' => 'rounds#present_survey'
        put 'survey' => 'rounds#store_survey'
      end
    end
    resources :questions
    resources :rounds
    member do
      get 'report' => 'reports#report'
      get 'bulk_add_participants'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `bulk_add_participants_program_url` is not recognized either? Running `rake routes` says something about these routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not finding the route because you have `programs` defined as a plural resource:

```
resources :programs do
```

When you do that and reference a `member` route like your `bulk_add_participants`, it expects a `:program_id` parameter in your case. (Try running `rake routes`, and you'll see a path like `/programs/:program_id/bulk_add_participants`.)

So your `form_tag` call should perhaps look like this:

```
<%= form_tag bulk_add_participants_program_path(@program) do %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been burned by that before, thanks for the extra set-o-eyes!

Comment: You're welcome. `rake routes` is your friend in situations like this.

Comment: Oh but I did rake routes multiple times and I saw the /1/ in the routes and tried them etc. But my brain didn't connect the need for the parameter to the call site. Bad brain. Thanks!